# Is there a way to iterate over a NotesDocumentCollection containing a deletion stub using only GetFirst/NextDocument?

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm working in several scripts iterating responses collections for main documents which get replicated, and I'm hitting a problem.

If I obtain a NotesDocumentCollection which contains one or more deletion stubs, when I iterate with GetNextDocument I get a NotesDocument object which has no attributes (`doc.IsValid` is False, `doc.IsDeleted` is True, and accessing any field or property causes an error and the UniversalID is blank). I cannot use this stub to collect the next document in the collection because I get an error that the document is deleted, nor can I remove it from the collection for the same reason.

What can I do to continue the iteration in the existing collection?

Comment: Have you tried the Subtract method to see if it can remove the deleted NotesDocument from the collection?  I.e., save the prev document, call getNextDocument, then do a while (doc.isDeleted)  and call Subtract followed by another getNextDocument(savedPrevDoc) in the loop body.

Comment: I will try that, I was using DeleteDocument but Subtract seems a good candidate.

Comment: And did you try with a NoteViewEntryCollection?

Comment: @D.Bugger: That approach wouldn't help me if what I'm iterating is the Responses collection of a NotesDocument.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz : I tried your suggestion but I'm trying to do this from a script in another language using COM and I'm supporting an 8.5 installation; Subtract is not exposed in COM, I'm afraid.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Oh, well.  But I'm not sure why you've ruled out the NotesViewEntry collection route. Yes, you can't use the Responses collection, but as long as there is an existing hierarchical view, or you can add one, I would think you start with your NotesDocument, create a NotesViewNavigator on a hierarchical view containing the document and its children, set entry = nvNav.getEntry(doc), then set childEntry = nvNav.getNext(entry).

Comment: I was trying to create a generic solution for NotesDocumentCollections to abstract into a library, to be able to iterate the collection in Python. Apparently it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an isDeleted property you can check before proceeding the document.

Comment: Yes, I can check IsValid and IsDeleted, but the question is how to access the next document from the collection if IsValid is false or IsDeleted is true, as those values give the error I describe.

I still have to test the solution proposed by Richard Schwartz, I'll comment on my results.